# Show "Go to App" popup directly from news feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, popup, facebook-oauth

I've seen this behavior only for Yahoo! News "social reader".

- I see in my Facebook news feed " read  on Yahoo!"
- I click on the  and a **popup is shown** to install the Yahoo! app (not a redirect to a new page, the popup is above my news feed)
- I click on "Go to App" and I'm taken on yahoo.com/.../article

Is this documented somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality called [Authenticated Referrals](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals) and described on [Auth Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/) documentation (**Enhanced Auth Dialog** should be enabled in application settings)